# How does Python importing exactly work?

Tags: python, import, module

I have two specific situations where I don't understand how importing works in Python:

**1st specific situation:**

When I import the same module in two different Python scripts, the module isn't imported twice, right? The first time Python encounters it, it is imported, and second time, does it check if the module has been imported, or does it make a copy?

**2nd specific situation:**

Consider the following module, called `bla.py`:

```
a = 10
```

And then, we have `foo.py`, a module which imports `bla.py`:

```
from bla import *

def Stuff ():
    return a
```

And after that, we have a script called `bar.py`, which gets executed by the user:

```
from foo import *
Stuff() #This should return 10 
a = 5
Stuff()
```

Here I don't know: Does `Stuff()` return 10 or 5?

Comment: What happened when you ran the code?

Comment: You may find these interesting: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/9/21/python-import-blackbox/ and http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2009/7/24/singletons-and-their-problems-in-python/. They both treat imports in Python.

Comment: Since 'from foo import *' brings everything from module foo into the local name space of bar, so we have both function Stuff and variable 'a' in local namespace of bar [as though they were created in bar module], then why does setting a to 5 and calling stuff in the bar module not return 5?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Part 1**

The module is only loaded once, so there is no performance loss by importing it again. If you actually wanted it to be loaded/parsed again, you'd have to `reload()` the module.

> The first place checked is `sys.modules`, the cache of all modules that have been imported previously. <sup>[[source](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)]</sup>

---

**Part 2**

`from foo import *` imports `a` to the local scope. When assigning a value to `a`, it is replaced with the new value - but the original `foo.a` variable is not touched.

So unless you `import foo` and modify `foo.a`, both calls will return the same value.

For a mutable type such as a list or dict it would be different, modifying it would indeed affect the original variable - but assigning a new value to it would still not modify `foo.whatever`.

If you want some more detailed information, have a look at http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html:

> The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions, **import statements**, class and function definitions (these bind the class or function name in the defining block), and **targets that are identifiers if occurring in an assignment**, for loop header, in the second position of an except clause header or after as in a with statement.

The two bold sections are the relevant ones for you: First the name `a` is bound to the value of `foo.a` during the import. Then, when doing `a = 5`, the name `a` is bound to `5`. Since modifying a list/dict does not cause any binding, those operations would modify the original one (`b` and `foo.b` are bound to the same object on which you operate). Assigning a new object to `b` would be a binding operation again and thus separate `b` from `foo.b`.

It is also worth noting what exactly the `import` statement does:

- `import foo` binds the module name to the module object in the current scope, so if you modify `foo.whatever`, you will work with the name in that module - any modifications/assignments will affect the variable in the module.
- `from foo import bar` binds the given name(s) only (i.e. `foo` will remain unbound) to the element with the same name in `foo` - so operations on `bar` behave like explained earlier.
- `from foo import *` behaves like the previous one, but it imports all global names which are not prefixed with an underscore. If the module defines `__all__` only names inside this sequence are imported.

---

**Part 3** (which doesn't even exist in your question :p)

The python documentation is extremely good and usually verbose - you find answer on almost every possible language-related question in there. Here are some useful links:

- http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html (classes, properties, magic methods, etc.) ()
- http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html (how variables work in python)
- http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html
- http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html (statements such as `import`, `yield`)
- http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html (block statements such as `for`, `try`, `with`)

Comment: Since 'from foo import *' brings everything from module foo into the local name space of bar, so we have both function Stuff and variable 'a' in local namespace of bar [as though they were created in bar module], then why does setting a to 5 and calling stuff in the bar module not return 5?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question:

No, python does not get 'imported' twice.  When python loads a module, it checks for the module in [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules).  If it is not in there, it is put in there, and loaded.

To answer your second question:

Modules can define what names they will export to a `from camelot import *` scenario, and the behavior is to create names for the existing values, not to reference existing variables (python does not have references).

On a somewhat related topic, doing a `from camelot import *` is [not the same as a regular import](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Looks like ThiefMaster beat me to answering the edit.  I'm leaving this here just to keep the "`from camelot import *` is not the same as a regular import."

Comment: Since 'from foo import *' brings everything from module foo into the local name space of bar, so we have both function Stuff and variable 'a' in local namespace of bar [as though they were created in bar module], then why does setting a to 5 and calling stuff in the bar module not return 5?