# Python dynamic loads modules/packages conflict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to load python(2.7 not 3.x) modules from source code dynamically using `imp.load_source` and if I dont't append the source code path to `sys.path` the local import can't work. In this case, How to resolve the conflict module name via local import?

I have been search a while and can't find a solution for this. Any ideas? Thanks!

The file structure what I have like this:

```
/tmp
|---runner
|   |-runner.py

/tmp/modules
|---bundle1
|   |--bundle
|   | |-__init__.py
|   | |-index.py
|   |-main.py
|
|---bundle2
    |--bundle
    | |-__init__.py
    | |-index.py
    |-main.py
```

In **runner.py**

```
import os
import imp
import sys

sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle1")
module_a = imp.load_source("Bundle1", "/tmp/modules/bundle1/main.py")
sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle2")
module_b = imp.load_source("Bundle2", "/tmp/modules/bundle2/main.py")

module_a.start()
module_b.start()
```

In **bundle1/main.py**

```
from bundle import index
def start():
    index.a_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

In **bundle2/main.py**

```
from bundle import index
def start():
    index.b_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Because the conflict of `from bundle`, `b_func()` can't be found in `bundle2/main.py`

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you should take a look at the `setuptools` package ?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that imports are being mixed up. Python is caching the fact that it knows about a module called `bundle` as well as a module called `bundle.index`. [This post should help you understand imports a little more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501768/1401328) This becomes a little less mystifying if you print out `sys.modules['bundle']` in between your loads.

```
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => yields None

sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle1")
module_a = imp.load_source("Bundle1", "/tmp/modules/bundle1/main.py")
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => <module 'bundle' from '/tmp/modules/bundle1/bundle/__init__.pyc>

sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle2")
module_b = imp.load_source("Bundle2", "/tmp/modules/bundle2/main.py")
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => <module 'bundle' from '/tmp/modules/bundle1/bundle/__init__.pyc>
```

If you have some real need for loading the exact same module name twice in one namespace, you'll need to blow away the entry in `sys.modules` in between. In addition, since you're just appending to your path, when you load `module_b` python will find `/tmp/modules/bundle1/bundle/` before it will find `/tmp/modules/bundle2/bundle` So, to completely solve you're problem you'll have to either prepend your information or remove it from the `sys.path` **In general though, this really isn't great practice and certainly if you have any control over the module names, you should change them.**

```
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => yields None

sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle1")
module_a = imp.load_source("Bundle1", "/tmp/modules/bundle1/main.py")
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => <module 'bundle' from '/tmp/modules/bundle1/bundle/__init__.pyc>

module_a.start()

# Delete python's knowledge of bundle1
del sys.modules['bundle']
del sys.modules['bundle.index']
sys.path.pop(sys.path.index('/tmp/modules/bundle1')

sys.path.append("/tmp/modules/bundle2")
module_b = imp.load_source("Bundle2", "/tmp/modules/bundle2/main.py")
print sys.modules.get('bundle', None)
# => <module 'bundle' from '/tmp/modules/bundle2/bundle/__init__.pyc>

module_b.start()
```

Please note that since you deleted python's knowledge of bundle1, that attempting: `moudle_a.start()` after the `del` will result in an `AttributeError`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, I know that will mixed up `sys.modules`... Is there any isolation/container tricks?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, short of what I posted above. You could certainly write your own hacks though. Perhaps consider using a class through the `with` syntax?