# Access to imports made from separate files in python?

Tags: python, module, modular

So I'm making a modular program for a security system in python, but I can't access modules I've imported in main.py from other scripts.

That is, say I have main.py that imports the random module.
I use import camClass to import a script containing an object class from camClass.py in the same directory. When I try to use the random module from within the class in camClass.py, it is undefined.

How do I overcome this error?

If I have to reimport the module from within camClass.py, where do I do it? In the **init** function? Or just at the top of the script? Thanks

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you are using a separate file for every class.  You should reconsider why you're doing that.  It often doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python importing exactly work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501724/how-does-python-importing-exactly-work)

Comment: Especially part about module not being imported every single time.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I overcome this error?

Every file that wants to use a certain module has to import that module.

> If I have to reimport the module from within camClass.py,

Yes, you do.

> where do I do it? In the init function? Or just at the top of the script?

At the top of the module is the standard place.  (Modules do not have an "init function".)