# Proper way of implementing one function per file in Python

Tags: python

I'm developing a module to help me deal with files, that's the structure:

```
Archive/
| archive/
  - __init__.py
  - move.py
  - rename.py
  - mime_type.py
| setup.py
```

I'm designing one file - one function. For me, it's better, i feel more comfortable with this style since i have an Node.js and C/C++ background.

So, my doubt is about how to implement the `__init__.py` to be able to call the functions using:

```
from archive import move
from archive import rename
from archive import mime_type
```

Instead of:

```
from archive import move.move
from archive import rename.rename
from archive import mime_type.mime_type
```

I'm doing like this:

```
__init__.py

from move import move
from rename import rename
from mime_type import mime_type
```

Is there an easier way to achieve automatically this behaviour? Without the necessity of changing the `__init__.py` each time i create an file.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are stuck with this. Python generally does not follow single-file for single-function code structure, so there probably isn't a "proper" way.  A single file should be a *module*, a collections of functions.You are making it more difficult for yourself doing it that way.

Comment: The os module might help.

Comment: Can't believe in this statement @juanpa.arrivillaga, i feel much more comfortable using this design, and that's all it is, a design decision. I think is so much easier to find functions, maintain, read and extend. Also, if i have one function per file, it's more clear which dependencies the function need to run.

Comment: @FXAMN well, then you will have to do some hacking in your `__init__`. It will require probably `os` and `importlib` as stated in some comments/answers. It will be confusing for someone who reads your code, that's for sure. Sure, it is a design decision, but you are using a tool, Python, that makes that design decision difficult to implement. This is your choice, though. In short, there is no "easy" way, and you will have to implement some hack to achieve it.

Comment: Cool, i'm going to search about it. About the confusion, i think this can be solved with a good readme, don't you think? I'm also developing this module that parses modules with this design and creates a 3d graphic showing how functions related to each other.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ has a one-function-per-file structure, and I'm not a Node user, but I'm pretty sure Node doesn't work that way either. If you're carrying these practices from your experience in C, C++, and Node, you were writing really weird and unwieldy code in those languages, too.

Comment: There are a lot of libs written with this design @user2357112, just search about it.

Comment: @user2357112 - C and C++ can both be written one function or class per file and some coding standards require it. In C++ especially, one .hpp per .cpp with single-class implementation is common.

Comment: @tdelaney: You certainly *can* write one function per file in C or C++, just as you *can* write one function per file in Python, but I've never seen any major projects work that way. One class per file isn't that uncommon, but that's not what we're talking about here.

Comment: Really don't get it why do you see this as a problem.. this won't affect performance, this won't make the code unreadable... is just a design decision... if i expose my code to the world, the api will be exactly the same, the performance also.. isn't Python a flexibly language? @user2357112

Comment: @FXAMN: For non-opinion-based reasons, you'll get slower imports and more potential for circular import problems.

Comment: Could you explain me why would be more slower? As pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501724/how-does-python-importing-exactly-work this would not affect the speed.

Comment: @FXAMN: That link says nothing to support your claim. As for why it'd be slower, you're making more filesystem calls and reading more files and directories.

Comment: Ok, read this one: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm This article explain exactly how it works: "This means that it’s fairly cheap to import an already imported module; Python just has to look the module name up in a dictionary.".

Comment: About the circular dependencies i must agree, but this is easy to avoid or fix.

Comment: It's cheap to import an already-imported module, but I'm not talking about already-imported modules. I'm talking about the first time you import your `archive` package, when you'll be searching your directory and reading a whole bunch of individual files.

Comment: If this is the cost for a more readable code, i don't mine at all since the difference will be minimum. It's a great trade off.

Comment: Maybe this use case makes sense? I'm using a similar structure for a data analysis project where I make several very different figures. It makes sense to group these under a common folder called visualization, and using this format I can run the code as standalone scripts to produce high-quality figures, as well as import the code in an illustrative notebook, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to import the modules and then assign the function names dynamically using [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
from importlib import import_module
for f in ["move","rename","mime_type"]:
    import_module("."+f,"archive") #import archive.f
    globals()[f]=getattr(globals[f],f) #assign the function f.f to variable f
```

As suggested by [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney), you can even get all the module names dynamically using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
from os.path import splitext,join,basename,dirname
from glob import glob  
#get all *.py filenames in __file__'s folder that are not __file__.
files=[splitext(f)[0] for f in glob(join(dirname(__file__), '*.py')) 
       if f != basename(__file__)] 
for f in files:
    ...
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: You could add `glob.glob("*.py")` and `os.path.splitext` to take it a step further.

Comment: well... make that `glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), '*.py'))` but the general idea was there.

Comment: The OP wants to import the functions, not just the modules.

Comment: Yeah, the fourth line of the first code block assigns the functions in the modules to the function names in the current module.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'as':

```
from archive import move.move as move
from archive import rename.rename as rename
from archive import mime_type.mime_type as mime_type
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: using the as keyword bind the local namespace for the module. so on an imported you can call move(x) rather than move.move(x)

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Saulpila's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727931/6012085) I ended up with the following:

```
import os.path
from glob import glob

# Get all *.py filenames in __init__'s folder
full_paths = glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.py'))

# Remove path prefix and remove __init__.py from the list
file_names = [os.path.split(f)[1] for f in full_paths if f != __file__]

# Remove extension
files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in file_names]

for f in files:
    # from archive import f (__name__ is 'archive')
    __import__(__name__+'.'+f, globals=globals())

    # assign the function f.main to variable f
    globals()[f]=getattr(globals()[f], 'main')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### My way is to use `exec()`.

```py
__init__.py

import glob
mod_list = [file_name.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] for file_name in glob.glob(__path__[0]+'/[!_]*.py')]
sub_pack_list = [folder_name.split('/')[-2] for folder_name in glob.glob(__path__[0]+'/[!_]*/')]

# import functions
for mod in mod_list:
    exec('from . import ' + mod)
    exec('from .' + mod + ' import *')

# import subpackages
for pack in sub_pack_list:
    exec('from . import ' + pack)

# clean up
del glob
try:
    del mod
except:
    pass
try:
    del pack
except:
    pass
```

After `import archive`, you will see `archive.move()` available to you.

As a bonus effect, you have `archive.mod_list` and `archive.sub_pack_list` available. If you don't like them, you can also delete them in `__init__.py`.

#### One step further

You can still have multiple functions in a file, say you have two functions `move_file()` and `move_folder()` in your `move.py`. You can add a final line

```py
__all__ = ['move_file', 'move_folder']
```

in `move.py` to control what functions should be available in the scope of `archive.***`

Comment: Why not put the `del mod` and `del pack` inside of the for loops?
you won't get a syntax error since the loop doesn't run if there are no items.