# how does import in python work? When import does python run the code in it?

Tags: python, python-import

when I import a python file (let's call it **x.py**) to another file (let's call it **y.py**)
will the computer run x.py the moment I import it to y.py?

so that if a code is originally only called once in x.py, will now run twice because y.py import it?
if it is true, how to avoid this to happen?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `how does import in python work?` into a search engine? When [I tried it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+does+import+in+python+work%3F), the [first result](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) I got was the official documentation. The [second result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501724/how-does-python-importing-exactly-work) I got was the linked duplicate. It's even *specifically* about your "will it run twice" question. There are further links that give you more information. Please read [ask]; you are expected to do basic research.

Comment: "how to avoid this to happen" Put the code in a function and call it once.